# can some body help me with ng-mouseover and ng-mouseleave in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a code like this in my html:

```
<div ng-mouseover="show_up()" ng-mouseleave="dont_show_up()" class="contain">
    <img src="image/first_image.jpg">
    <div class="overlay" ng-style="overlay">
        <a href="#!" class="text">show songs</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div ng-mouseover="show_up()" ng-mouseleave="dont_show_up()" class="contain">
    <img  src="image/second_image.jpg">
    <div class="overlay" ng-style="overlay">
        <a href="#!" class="text">show songs</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this is my js code :

```
$scope.show_up = function () {
       $scope.overlay={
           "height":"100%"
       };
    };
    $scope.dont_show_up = function () {
        $scope.overlay={
            "height":"0"
        };
    }
```

this is what I need to happen: whenever I hover on my first image it should add the style "height:100%"
to my first image, not both of them!
and when I hover on my second image it should add the style "height:100%"
to my second image, not both of them!
how can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you are trying to achieve since you state you want the image to change from 0 - 100% on the mouseover - but the ng-style is applied to the overlay. I assume you are trying to overlay the text over the image?

Anyway you don't need angular or even javascript for this - just CSS and apply a :hover on the parent level and style on the child element and you can achieve the desired outcome without the cost of the js.

```css
.overlay {
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden
}

.contain:hover .overlay {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="contain">
    <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/3e/6b/cd/3e6bcdc46881f5355163f9783c44a985.jpg" height="150">
    <div class="overlay">
        <a href="#!" class="text">show songs</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div  class="contain">
    <img  src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61W2FTW9ePL._AC_SL1500_.jpg" height="150">
    <div class="overlay">
        <a href="#!" class="text">show songs</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, what you said is completely correct.Im trying to overlay the some text over the my images.since Im new to angularjs and Im recently working on it, I just wanted to do it with angularjs!!

Answer (score 2):

**One solution** would be passing some value to `show_up()` and `dont_show_up()` function, which identifies an image, say 1, 2 and then, inside function, change `overlay` variable to array and update appropriate item. `ng-style="overlay"` must be also changed to `ng-style="overlays[0]"`

--Edit

```html
<div ng-mouseover="show_up(0)" ng-mouseleave="dont_show_up(0)" class="contain">
    <img src="image/first_image.jpg">
    <div class="overlay" ng-style="overlays[0]">
        <a href="#!" class="text">show songs</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div ng-mouseover="show_up(1)" ng-mouseleave="dont_show_up(1)" class="contain">
    <img  src="image/second_image.jpg">
    <div class="overlay" ng-style="overlays[1]">
        <a href="#!" class="text">show songs</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
$scope.show_up = function (index) {
  $scope.overlays[index] = {
    "height":"100%"
  };
};
$scope.dont_show_up = function (index) {
  $scope.overlays[index] = {
    "height":"0"
  };
}
```

**Well that becomes difficult to maintain when number of images increase**

**Second solution.**
You can store all images as an array of objects and apply `ng-repeat` directive to loop through them.

```html
<div ng-repeat="image in images" ng-mouseover="show_up(image.id)" ng-mouseleave="dont_show_up(image.id)" class="contain">
    <img ng-src="image.src">
    <div class="overlay" ng-style="image.overlay">
        <a href="#!" class="text">show songs</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
$scope.show_up = function (id) {
    $scope.images.find(image => image.id === id).overlay = {
      "height":"100%"
    };
  };
$scope.dont_show_up = function (id) {
   $scope.images.find(image => image.id === id).overlay = {
     "height":"0"
   };
  }
```

Comment: thanks for your answer ,I have tried the second solution and it works perfectly, but could you please explain the first one? I did not thoroughly get what you mean.

Comment: I don't know why but the first solution does not work!why should I change "overlay" class to "overlays".because Im trying to change one of  "overlay" properties which is "height" from "0" to "100%".

Comment: You have to change `overlay` variable name to `overlays` and it should be an array of objects [{"height":"0"}, {"height":"0"}]